# Error: Cannot find module './server/checkNodeVersion'

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I want to open a project with Expo, but the Devtools crash.

I already reinstall `nodejs` and `Expo-cli`. It's not improve anything.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
```

throw err;

```
Error: Cannot find module ' ./server/checkNodeVersion '
```

Comment: have you checked node version

Comment: node -v  v10.16.0